# Get <li> with child <ul> from <ul> child of <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple example of a menu here:

```
<ul id="1">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a>
    <ul id="2">
        <li><a href="#">Second - 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second - 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second - 3</a>
        <ul id="3">
            <li><a href="#">Aaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ccc</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the `<li>` that has a child `<ul>` and that is a child of `<ul>` who is a child of `<li>`, and apply a style to it.

I know it sounds complicated, but in the example above I want to get only the `<li>` that says "Second - 3" which is inside a ul, which is a child of a li and has a child ul. I don't want to get any other `<li>`s.

I can't do this without getting also the li which says "Second", and I don't want that.

```
$("li > ul").addClass('whatever');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$("li ul li:has(ul)")`

e.g:

```
$(function(){
    var items = $("li ul li:has(ul)");
    alert(items.html());
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EXzaa/

Comment: That is excellent and works perfectly. Thanks a lot!! Knowledge is power!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("li > ul > li").each(function(){
    if ( $(this).find("ul").length > 0){
        $(this).css({"font-weight":"bold"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Cybernate's solution is much better, however.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I get you wrong this is simple. Try something like this:

```
$('#3').parent('li').addClass('whatever');
```

This will select the parent node of the `ul` element with the id = 3 (only if it is an `li` element)